# TYPO3 which file consists code with user logining?

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 version 7.6.18. I try to make auto login user after registration. I can't do it for now. Just one little question. Tell me please which file consists code with handler of post data (username, password) which come from fe_login form. I check all fe_login plugin and I did't find this. I hope you understand me right. I just looking file where happening getting post data and making session so user login. Help me please, anybody )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the backend and the frontend use authentication services to authenticate a user.

Please look in the file `typo3/sysext/sv/Classes/AuthenticationService.php`. The function `public function authUser(array $user)` receives an array from the login form and validates the credtials.

Please note, that TYPO3 can uses more than one authentication service in a given priority. You will find a list of installed authentication services in the Reports backend module (see screenshot)

[image: TYPO3 Authentication Services]

In case you have installed salted passwords extension (which is default), the validation of the login credentials is being processed in `typo3/sysext/saltedpasswords/Classes/SaltedPasswordService.php`.

All authentication services are being processed in the order of their priority (lower number to higher number). This is processed by the classes in `typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Authentication`.